# plainToInstance not working with Decimal as default value

Tags: decimal, nest, class-transformer

I'm using the class-transformer's plainToInstance to get some values from other values. The minimal example of the problem I met is represented in the following code:

```
class MyClass {
  readonly attempts: number = 1;

  readonly totalDistance: number = 1;
  
  @Transform(({ obj }) => new Decimal(obj.totalDistance).div(obj.attempts))
  readonly distancePerAttempt: Decimal = new Decimal(0);
}
```

And use MyClass this way:

```
plainToInstance(
  MyClass,
  {
    attempts: 3,
    totalDistance: 30,
  },
);
```

And the error I get is:

```
[Nest] 51628  - 07/29/2023, 10:44:03 PM   ERROR [AllExceptionsFilter] Error: [DecimalError] Invalid argument: undefined
    at new Decimal (/Users/.../node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:30312:13)
    at TransformOperationExecutor.transform (/Users/.../node_modules/src/TransformOperationExecutor.ts:160:22)
    at TransformOperationExecutor.transform (/Users/.../node_modules/src/TransformOperationExecutor.ts:333:33)
    at ClassTransformer.plainToInstance (/Users/.../node_modules/src/ClassTransformer.ts:77:21)
    at plainToInstance (/Users/.../node_modules/src/index.ts:84:27)
...
```

The error doesn't appear if I don't supply distancePerAttempt with a default value, but in this case, @Transform won't be applied.

Can anybody confirm this is the bug, or show me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

you need to wrap `Decimal` object and use your wrapper class all around your project instead:

```js
export DecimalNumber extends Decimal {
 constructor(value = 0) { super(value); }
}

class Dto {
 @Type(() => DecimalNumber)
 @Transform(...)
 number: DecimalNumber
}
```

see a related thread on github: https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/issues/1270